# Curl command does not do what I exoect in Batch

Tags: curl, batch-file, cmd

Why this curl command does not work in CMD. It should downlaod a html page with headers but it looks like some binary data recieved..

```
curl -o tested.htm -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100214 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.8" ^
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" ^
-H "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" ^
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" ^
-H "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" ^
-H "Keep-Alive: 300" ^
-H "Connection: keep-alive" http://request.urih.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" ^
```

Should not be there for html page